# How to select the listviewitem, where a button was clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listview, listviewitem

i want to select a listviewitem, where a button was clicked.

[Here is my Listview with 2 llistviewitems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIqFw.png)

I click the X-Button and want to delete these item out of the list. How i get that item?
I have these code:

```
 private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as ListViewItem;

            var obj = item.Content as object;

            List.Remove(obj);
     }
```

Edit: The Binding of the ListView

```
       <ListView x:Name="listview">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Bild     "/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="Change" Content="Change" Margin="250,0,0,0" Click="Change_Click"/>
                        <Button x:Name="Delete" Content="X" Margin="10,0,0,0" Click="Delete_Click"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="lvSeriesItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Can you post how you are binding data to the `listview`.

Comment: I have edit the post

Comment: Where you are setting the `ItemSource` for the ListView ?

Comment: In an method which is lines before the code: `listview.itemssource = list;`

Comment: What you are getting when you try to debug line by line in `Delete_click` event.  Definitely there is a problem with `casting` the item to be removed.

Comment: If you can get the ListViewItem then the object that is binded to it should be in ListViewItem.DataContext and not in ListViewItem.Content

Comment: By the `var obj = item.content as Object` i get these message:  Object reference not set to an object instance.

Comment: But the item is `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use this instead.The control that raised the event is not the listbox but the button.The button as a datacontext of your collection model object. so this should workd

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button= sender as Button;    
         var obj =(YourModelHere)button.DataContext;

            List.Remove(obj);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

`sender` will be the `Button`, your data item will be the `DataContext` of said button.

Comment: how you mean that, that the sender the button is ok, but what should i do?

Comment: Cast it to `Button` (don't use `as`), then cast its `DataContext` to your data item class, then you can remove that from your item list. By the way, use `ObservableCollection` if you assign an `ListView.ItemsSource` (which you should be doing).